# Excel, 2>1 = False, How?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Anyone care to explain what happened?
Originally, I tried to use `text()` for a date and compare it with number

But I use a simple example here as my excel is too messy right now.
example:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Because Text is not a number even if it looks like one.

Comment: And a Date is not Text even if it looks like Text

Comment: text is always bigger than number. i dunno why. but just know it and be alert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"1"` and `1` are different things.

Excel can implicitly convert `"1"` to `1` in certain contexts, but `2 > "1"` does *not* trigger that conversion. Instead, a number is always treated as "less than" text. (Hat-tip to [Jeeped](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4039065/jeeped) for pointing out this last part.)

To address this, you can force a numeric conversion by writing (for example):

```
= F5 > (0+G5)
```

Comment: **2** (as number) sorts as 'less than' `"1"` (as text) because true numbers always sort less than text. See [sample](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Gztmf.png).

Comment: @Jeeped: I've now added that information to the answer; thank you!

Comment: You are welcome to add that sample image to your answer. It is already on http://i.stack.imgur.com/Gztmf.png.